# Is there a word for 'religism'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, questions

I'm searching for a word with a meaning similar to Racism or Sexism but within the context of religion. Is there a word for this meaning?

Comment: @tchrist An all encompassing word for prejudice towards the religious in general.

Comment: Religious bigotry comes to mind.